# Many-to-Many gives no result

Tags: php, mysql, join, many-to-many

at first my Many-to-Many-Relationship is with the following tables:

```
+----------+      +--------------+     
| users    |      | users_groups |     +--------------+
+----------+      +--------------+     | groups       |
| user_id  |----->| user_id      |     +--------------+
| username |      | group_id     |<----| group_id     |
| realname |      +--------------+     | group_name   |
| password |                           | group_desc   |
+----------+                           +--------------+
```

Now I want to get a list/table (not a table in the DB!) of all existing groups with all the users of the specific group, something like this:

```
+---------------+--------------------------+
| group         | members                  |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Group1        | User1, User2, User3      |
| Group2        | User3, User4, User6      |
| Group3        |                          |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

My current MySQL code is:

```
$all_groups = mysqli_query
            ($db,
            "
            SELECT g.group_name,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.realname SEPARATOR ', ') AS users
            FROM groups g
            JOIN users_groups ug1 ON g.group_id=ug1.group_id
            JOIN users u ON ug1.user_id=u.user_id
            GROUP BY g.group_name
            "
            );
```

My current PHP-Code is:

```
while($row_all_groups = mysqli_fetch_array($all_groups)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="td_contentbar">'.$row_all_groups["group_name"].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="td_contentbar">'.$row_all_groups["users"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

But the problem is that **if a group has no users (in users_groups-table) the group isn't shown in the list/table i have** and I have no idea how to solve this.

Replacing `JOIN users_groups` with `LEFT JOIN users_groups` did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need a `left join`:

```
SELECT g.group_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.realname SEPARATOR ', ') AS users
FROM groups g LEFT JOIN
     users_groups ug1
     ON g.group_id = ug1.group_id LEFT JOIN
     users u ON ug1.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY g.group_name;
```

When using `LEFT JOIN`, normally you put the table with the rows you want to keep first.  Then you use `LEFT JOIN` for all the subsequent joins.

Also, your data probably has no duplicate user names in a group.  The `DISTINCT` keyword hurts performance and should only be used when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in PHP, but i can give you another way to resolve this. (gonna write in C# logic)

First bring a table relating all groups with users (use left joint to bring even groups without users)

```
        SELECT g.group_name, u.realname AS users
        FROM groups g
        LEFT JOIN users_groups ug1 ON g.group_id=ug1.group_id
        JOIN users u ON ug1.user_id=u.user_id
```

then do kinda like this in PHP

```
$TEMP_VAR_LAST_GROUP = "NOGROUPNAMEATALL";
$I_HAVE_DATA = "FALSE";
while($row_all_groups = mysqli_fetch_array($all_groups)) {

   $I_HAVE_DATA = "TRUE";

   if($TEMP_VAR_LAST_GROUP != "NOGROUPNAMEATALL")
   {
       // This is just to close the tags after the last loop
       echo '</td></tr>'
   }


   If ($TEMP_VAR_LAST_GROUP == $row_all_groups["group_name"])
   {
      // this is a new group
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td class="td_contentbar">'.$row_all_groups["group_name"].'</td>';
      echo '<td class="td_contentbar">'.$row_all_groups["users"].'
   }
   else
   {
      // this is the same group, but new user
      echo ','.$row_all_groups["users"].'
   }

   // SETS A NEW LASST GROUP VAR
   $TEMP_VAR_LAST_GROUP == $row_all_groups["group_name"])

}

// This will close the last tags if the table has data
if($I_HAVE_DATA = "TRUE")
{
   echo '</td></tr>'
}
```